# Harmonic Progression Question from an Olympiad.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A harmonic progression is a sequence of the form

$$ \frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{a + d}, \frac{1}{a + 2d}, \ldots, \frac{1}{a + kd} $$

where $ k $ is a natural number. The question asks me to prove that there exist arbitrarily long harmonic sequences consisting of integers only.

The longest sequence I've been able to find consists of $ 3 $ integers. I would appreciate some hints to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the factorial function.

**Hint #2**: Look at the harmonic progressions $ 6, 3, 2 $ and $ 24, 12, 8, 6 $. Generalize.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why he/she downvoted the answer?

Comment: I can't understand how factorial would help, are you implying me do something like this,

Comment: Is  1! =1 & 2!=4 you are trying to hint at.

Comment: Got it isn't it in form of 1/1!+1, 1/2!+1, and for last term it is 1/n!.

Comment: Since you already included that second hint in your comment, might as well edit it into your answer.